# How to respond to plagiarized answers

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

When I discover that an answer has been blatantly stolen from another user's answer I never know whether to comment and ask the user to delete the post or whether to flag it for moderator attention.  What is the best course of action?

Comment: If it's in the same question, and the case is really really obvious, I would downvote, comment (if you're ready for the possible flame war, as Shadow Wizard mentions below), and flag. Also the user profiles of plagiators are often worth checking out - if you've done it once, chances are you've done it many times

Comment: Most likely it was done on purpose and maliciously so just flag. Commenting have big risk of starting a flame war with the offender, when he'll notice his missing answers and/or rep he'll get the point.